Can chartjs draw this kind of line chart with intervals?
Can chartjs draw this kind of line chart with intervals like this?

This is my option:
  const options11 = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    aspectRatio: 2,
    scales: {
      x: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Date'
        },
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 12, // 调整此值以减少X轴的标签数量
        }
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Variance'
        }
      }
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        right: 10,
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true
      },
      title: {
        display: false,
      },
      datalabels: {
        display: false,
      },
      filler: {
        propagate: false
      },
      'samples-filler-analyser': {
        target: 'chart-analyser'
      }
    },
    interaction: {
      intersect: false
    }
  };


Yes, it can. However, you have to provide a set of sample data and an explanation on what the "intervals" are - the image you posted is not very clear - there seems to be a horizontal black line inside each of the interval bars, but it's unknown where and how is that to be positioned.
